# How can I separate rows with a newline when exporting to CSV with Text::CSV?

Tags: perl

`my @rows` has the following data:

```
[
          [
            '',
            '2000',
            '2001',
            '2002',
            '2003',
            '2004',
            '2005',
            '2006',
            '2007',
            '2008',
            '2009',
            '2010',
            '2011',
            '2012',
            '2013',
            '2014',
            '2015',
            '2016',
            '2017'
          ],
          [
            'PA',
            1848,
            1851,
            1840,
            1783,
            1598,
            1084,
            1308,
            1170,
            1388,
            1326,
            1397,
            1452,
            1435,
            1425,
            1377,
            1343,
            420,
            30
          ]
]
```

I'm trying to export to a CSV with [`Text::CSV`.](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.91/lib/Text/CSV.pm) I have this code which is basically ripped from the doc page:

```
sub generate_csv_file {
  my $self = shift;
  my $rows = shift;

  open my $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "state_reports.csv" or logf("Can't open CSV file for writing");
  $self->csv->print ($fh, $_) for @$rows;
  close $fh or logf("Can't close CSV file");
}
```

The file it generates looks like this with all the data on one line:

```
,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017PA,1848,1851,1840,1783,1598,1084,1308,1170,1388,1326,1397,1452,1435,1425,1377,1343,420,30TX,1165,1198,1202,1177,1132,772,928,866,1024,946,982,1067,1068,1050,1038,1011,310,0
```

I've looked through the documentation but don't see any obvious way to separate the lines with a newline. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the record separator using the [`eol` option](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#eol) to `Text::CSV->new`:

> **eol**
>
> ```
> my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ eol => $/ });
>           $csv->eol (undef);
> my $eol = $csv->eol;
> ```
>
> The end-of-line string to add to rows for "print" or the record separator for "getline".
>
> [...]
>
> When not passed in a generating instance, records are not terminated at all, so it is probably wise to pass something you expect. A safe choice for `eol` on output is either `$/` or `\r\n`.

Comment: `"\r\n"`is *not* a safe choice. Perl applies the `:crlf` PerlIO layer to STDIN and STDOUT on Windows systems by default. That converts every `\n` to `\r\n` on output, so sending `\r\n` will result in `\r\r\n` at the end of every line of the file. You could `binmode STDOUT` and then use `\r\n` for `eol`, but I can't see why you would. `$/` is `"\n"` by default on both Windows and Linux. It may be the default everywhere, but I'm unsure about platforms like VMS or EBCDIC systems.

Comment: @Borodin Good catch, I'm not sure why H.Merijn Brand added that to the docs. I submitted a [ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=120145) (the Text::CSV docs are just a shameless copy of the Text::CSV_XS docs, so I'm starting at the source).

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me that `Text::CSV` was a core module. Well done.

Comment: @Borodin It's not. I guess Merijn does more than just work on core.

Comment: @Borodin In case you're curious, he [responded](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=120145#txn-1704484) to my ticket, although I'm not sure I follow his reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Three options:

1. Replace `$csv->print($fh, $row)` with `$csv->say($fh, $row)`.
2. Pass `eol => "\n"` to the constructor.
3. Follow up with `print($fh "\n");`.

Comment: Argh, I forgot about `say`! It was only added to Text::CSV_PP in the 1.91 release on 2017-01-28, even though it's been in Text::CSV_XS for a couple years.